# Which split testing tools can be used for ajax heavy sites?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I want to do split testing on my single page website. The website is written with node.js server-side and also relies on Javascript in the front-end. All the content is accessed through an API which is parsed into a template by the front-end client. I want to test, how certain changes in the visual appearance of the site influences bounce rate and facebook shares.

There are a lot of split or A/B testing tools out there, but which one fits this scenario?

Bonus points for heatmaps and more fancy data ;)

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer*: I'm founder of the product mentioned below.

You can try our product [Visual Website Optimizer](http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com) which has a jQuery based API to test dynamic elements and AJAX elements. You can also test CSS/JavaScript separately for different versions, so anything that you can modify using a JavaScript function, you can test that.

As a bonus, we do have heatmaps!

Comment: Hi Paras, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the product didn't work with my site. I can create different scenarios in the editor(which is really nice), but it won't work when I wanted to preview the the test.

Comment: Thomas, I am not sure if this is the right place to provide support but can you please contact us via the contact form provided inside the application. Our team would love to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Like Paras: I wrote the product that I'm mentioning...

www.instabir.com has a simple A/B testing plugin for jQuery. The tests configured and initiated in javascript, so you could run the function in a callback from your AJAX requests, for instance.

The code works like this:

```
$('.class-of-options').ab({
   testname: 'some identifier',
   action_el: $('#element_user_should_click')
});
```

As far as collecting the results, you can either run your own server or pay for a hosted results and presentation.

You can check out a demo here: www.instabir.com/demos

Answer (score 1):

I have had very good success using [Google Website Optimizer](http://www.google.com/websiteoptimizer) for such A/B testing.